Dynamically change a file name when using FFmpeg
I am currently trying to compress all of my video files (anywhere between 30GB and 500GB) and i have found out a way to get the batch file to run it for all of my files in a folder but it keeps giving me back 'this file already exists overwrite?[y/N]' however even if I press yes (i will be deleting the original files anyway) it will not allow me to do so as it cannot write to a file from the same file. I currently have this as my code
@echo off
set 0=compressed
for %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 24  "%%i%0.mp4"

though when i have %%i.mp4 or %%~ni.mp4 it will not change the output name to anything else. however I need it to
also as a side question how can i get ffmpeg to see subfolders too and not just the folder it is in?

Another very simple issue coming from using batch for no reason. This is a task doable in 5-10 minutes within PowerShell, without any cryptic syntaxes.

i want to be able to do it on muiltiple occasions not just tonight

What...? I think you have very big misunderstanding of scripting in Windows.

I probably do, but im trying to learn, using this platform has helped me greatly for automating certain actions that I use almost daily


@echo off

:: set   0=compressed  ❌
   set "_x=compressed" ✅

:: for %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i  "%%i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 24  "%%i%0.mp4"     ❌
   for %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 24  "%%~ni%_x%.mp4" ✅

You are using %0 as a variable, but in Batch scripting, %0 is interpreted as the name of the Batch file itself, including the path if provided.
Avoid using numbers for variable names. %0, %1, %2,, etc., are treated as arguments: %0 refers to the Batch file, while %1, %2, etc., refer to argument #1, #2, and so on. Avoid using numbers as variable names, and also avoid creating variable names that start with numbers.

Regarding the use of expansion for file names in a loop: "%%~ni%_x%.mp4" expands %%~ni to the file name without the extension, appending the value of %_x% and the .mp4.
Get to know and use Parameter Extensions properly...
%~f1  Expand %1 to a Fully qualified path name - C:\utils\MyFile.txt
%~d1  Expand %1 to a Drive letter only - C:
%~p1  Expand %1 to a Path only e.g. \utils\ this includes a trailing 
      \ which will be interpreted as an escape character by some commands.  
%~n1 Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension or path - MyFile 
      or if only a path is present, with no trailing backslash, the last folder in that path.  
%~x1  Expand %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt  
%~s1  Change the meaning of f, n, s and x to reference the Short 8.3 name (if it exists.)  
%~1   Expand %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")  
%~a1  Display the file attributes of %1  
%~t1  Display the date/time of %1

@echo off

set "_x=compressed"

for %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 24  "%%~ni%_x%.mp4"

:: or ...
for %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec libx265 -crf 24  "%%~dpni%_x%.mp4"



To do the same recursively across all subfolders, try using:
For /Recursively

@echo off

set "_x=compressed"

for /r %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%%~fi" -vcodec libx265 -crf 24  "%%~dpni%_x%.mp4"


Refer to the material posted in the links.

Set /?

For /?

For /R /?

An A-Z Index of Windows CMD commands on ss64.com



Thanks Man, that worked, although the parameters did not, i tried using the ones you recommended but it wouldn't look into the subfolders as I needed, However the main question was answered.

for does indeed not look into subfolders. you will need another for to check for each folder, then use its result in the other for loop.

@LPChip Thank you for your comment, but actually there's no need to use two for loops; a single for /r loop handles this directly. See in the edit, I added an example for recursion

Ah of course. I forgot about that option. I haven't used for in a long while, ever since I moved to PowerShell.

one more question, is there a way i can exclude some folders as well, namely hidden ones (like the rexycle bin)

Everything is possible here if you believe! But you need to open a question and post the elements participating in the scenario and the interest in reaching the action, and then you will have an answer that will suit you in the most specific and precise way possible. Other than that, it is a risk for you and someone may complain about the rules of what is allowed to be discussed in comments... please understand.
